# select insert query optimization on large volume MYSQL 8.x

Tags: mysql, query-performance

Im trying to run this SELECT query from table bidPrice that has over 160 million rows into a second table called spreads_v2

```
INSERT INTO spreads_v2(SELECT bp1.timestamp, bp1.idExchangePair, bp1.idRequest, bp1.idExchangePlatform AS idEp_a, bp2.idExchangePlatform AS idEp_b, bp1.lastPrice as lastPrice_a, bp2.lastPrice AS lastPrice_b,  
(SELECT IF (bp1.lastPrice> bp2.lastPrice,bp1.lastPrice,bp2.lastPrice)),
(SELECT (((ABS(bp1.lastPrice - bp2.lastPrice))*100)/(SELECT IF (bp1.lastPrice> bp2.lastPrice,bp1.lastPrice,bp2.lastPrice)))) AS spread_percentage,
ABS(bp1.lastPrice - bp2.lastPrice) AS spread_A_B
 FROM bidPrice AS bp1
JOIN bidPrice AS bp2
ON bp1.idRequest = bp2.idRequest AND bp1.idExchangePair = bp2.idExchangePair AND bp1.idExchangePlatform < bp2.idExchangePlatform)
```

The query works fine, i tested on a test db with the right output, but the issue comes when i run this into the production db that has large amounts of data, i ran into canceled query after 12 hours of execution.

heres the `SHOW CREATE table` for both

```
CREATE TABLE `bidPrice` (
  `idBidPrice` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idRequest` int NOT NULL,
  `idCurrencyPair` int NOT NULL,
  `idExchangePlatform` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `idExchangePair` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `bidPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `wholeApiResponse` longtext,
  `askPrice` double NOT NULL,
  `lastPrice` double NOT NULL,
  `lowPrice` double NOT NULL,
  `highPrice` double NOT NULL,
  `volumePrice` double NOT NULL,
  `platformTimestamp` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBidPrice`,`idRequest`,`idCurrencyPair`),
  KEY `idExchangePlatform` (`idExchangePlatform`),
  KEY `idExchangePair` (`idExchangePair`),
  CONSTRAINT `bidPrice_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idExchangePlatform`) REFERENCES `exchangePlatform` (`idExchangePlatform`),
  CONSTRAINT `bidPrice_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idExchangePair`) REFERENCES `exchangePair` (`idExchangePair`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=176759983 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


CREATE TABLE `spreads_v2` (
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `idExchangePair` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `idRequest` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `idExchangePlatform_A` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `idExchangePlatform_B` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `bidPrice_A` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `bidPrice_B` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `spread_percentage` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `spread_A_B` double DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idExchangePair` (`idExchangePair`,`idRequest`,`idExchangePlatform_A`,`idExchangePlatform_B`),
  KEY `idExchangePlatform_A` (`idExchangePlatform_A`),
  KEY `idExchangePlatform_B` (`idExchangePlatform_B`),
  CONSTRAINT `spreads_v2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idExchangePair`) REFERENCES `exchangePair` (`idExchangePair`),
  CONSTRAINT `spreads_v2_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idExchangePlatform_A`) REFERENCES `exchangePlatform` (`idExchangePlatform`),
  CONSTRAINT `spreads_v2_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`idExchangePlatform_B`) REFERENCES `exchangePlatform` (`idExchangePlatform`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

As an aditional comment, i have this database in a AWS RDS t2.micro, im considering on upgrading the db instance for query speed up.

Comment: I can say a **t2.micro** is definitely **way under-provisioned** for the amount of data you're trying to process (and probably at the rate that's acceptable to process it, seeing that it's financial data). You'll really likely want at least a **t2.large** (*maybe* you can get away with a **t2.medium**). In AWS you don't actually get the performance the same way as if you built the server in-house, and probably are generally better off adding a 25-50% buffer to what you think you need when comparing to their server lists. I've worked with *big* (10s of billions of rows) financial data in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing about your query is the indexing on `bidPrice` needs to map to your join criteria:

Hence the index on `bidPrice` should be:

```
idRequest, idExchangePair, idExchangePlatform
```

The first two can be in either order as both are referenced with an `=` and `idExchangePlatform` is a range `<` based search so leave this last.

Extend one of the existing indexes that begins with the same element(s).

The subquery `SELECT` statements in the query are ugly.

```
SELECT ...,
   GREATEST(bp1.lastPrice, bp2.lastPrice),
   (ABS(bp1.lastPrice - bp2.lastPrice))*100)/GREATEST(bp1.lastPrice, bp2.lastPrice)
```

will make it simpler (but probably won't help with speed significantly) - ref: [GREATEST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

To help with such a large scan, batch this up based on the first element of the index above.

So:

```
INSERT ... SELECT ... JOIN ... WHERE idRequest < 10000;
INSERT ... SELECT ... JOIN ... WHERE idRequest BETWEEN 10001 AND 20000;
....
```

Comment: More specifically, the first element of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  More discussion of chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Answer (score 1):

It's overkill to use a `SELECT` for just an expression.  And there is a simpler function:

```
(SELECT IF (bp1.lastPrice> bp2.lastPrice,bp1.lastPrice,bp2.lastPrice)),
```

-->

```
GREATEST(bp1.lastPrice, bp2.lastPrice)
```

and

```
SELECT  (((ABS(bp1.lastPrice - bp2.lastPrice))*100)/
         (  SELECT  IF (bp1.lastPrice > bp2.lastPrice,bp1.lastPrice,bp2.lastPrice))
        )
```

-->

```
100 * ABS(bp1.lastPrice - bp2.lastPrice) /
       GREATEST(bp1.lastPrice, bp2.lastPrice)
```

And add this index, with the columns in the given order:

```
INDEX(idExchangePair, idRequest, idExchangePlatform, lastPrice)
```

(Depending on what version you are using, adding the index may take a long time, but I think it will significantly speed up the query.)  Recommend you remove the index on just `idExchangePair` at the same time,

This puzzles me:

```
UNIQUE KEY `idExchangePair` 
          (`idExchangePair`,`idRequest`,
           `idExchangePlatform_A`,`idExchangePlatform_B`),
```

The columns are NULLable; perhaps they should not be?  What is an "exchange pair" if it is A and B, then the columns seem redundant?

There is no `PRIMARY KEY` for this table.  If those 4 columns were `NOT NULL`, they could be the PK.